# How to let shell return to the previous line after exiting a full-screen process like Vim

Tags: shell, zsh

I connect to **Z-Shell** on a Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.2 machine via **Putty**. After I exit a full-screen process, eg Vim and less, in Unix shell, the shell prompt starts at the last line of the screen. The screen above still shows the context of that process, so I lost all stuff that shell showed before I opened that process.

This doesn't happen in my own Ubuntu box, where after exiting a process, I get back to the line below the last command I typed.

What options can I change(maybe in `zshrc`?) to make it behave like my Ubuntu box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this problem too.  Check your PuTTY settings under Terminal->Features.  If "Disable switching to alternate terminal screen" is checked, uncheck it.  (All my settings on that page are unchecked.)  The help for that option looks promising.

Failing that, [this page](http://www.shallowsky.com/linux/noaltscreen.html) I found by googling might give you some ideas.  You might be able to set some terminfo stuff to get it working right.

Answer (score 1):

After fixing this very issue long ago, I ran into a similar problem, where Vim did not have this issue, but `less` did. This affected all programs that use `less` too, like `man`. The cause, I found, was the `LESS` environment variable, which lists arguments to automatically be passed to `less` whenever it is invoked. The option within `LESS` that caused this was `-X`:

> #### `-X` or `--no-init`
>
> Disables sending the termcap initialization and deinitialization strings to the terminal. This is sometimes desirable if the deinitialization string does something unnecessary, like clearing the screen.

I also learned from [Unix & Linux – “`less --quit-if-one-screen` without `--no-init`”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/107315/19874) that if you disable `-X`/`--no-init`, you must disable `-F`/`--quit-if-one-screen` too (if you have it set).

To fix `less` so that it always restores your screen on exit, change the value of `LESS` in the appropriate shell initialization file. This will be `.bashrc` for Bash, `.zshenv` for Zsh, and `.config/fish/config.fish` for Fish. To this file, add the command `export LESS='<all the flags you want, without -X or -F>'`, or `set -gx LESS <flags>` for fish. You can run `echo $LESS` beforehand to see the existing flags to copy into your `export`/`set` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! All I have to do is set `$TERM` to `xterm`. It used to be `linux`

```
export TERM=xterm
```

Thanks for the link and hints, David!